# Android: emulate a galaxy s4 with samsung os

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

is there a way to emulate a galaxy s4 with the actual samsung android version?
I mean, in Eclipse I can emulate the hardware of the s4, but then the os running is Android stock, while the one which is running into the s4 is customized by Samsung.

Is any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can not emulate Samsung OS, as they distribute their OS only as binarys for each device, and not as opensource.

So you can not use it on a different hardware than a Samsung Phone.